# Obtaining list of groups in Chef?

Tags: ruby, windows, active-directory, chef-infra

Brand new to Chef. I was curious if there's a way to obtain a list of groups in Chef? Essentially I want to create a restricted windows user who isn't a member of any group.
Something like:

```
TheseAreAllTheWindowsGroupsOnTheSystem.each do |groupName|
   group groupName do
        action :modify
        excluded_members: username
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ohai](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html) for this.

```rb
node['etc']['group'].each do |group_name, info|
  # ...
end
```

I do not have a Windows system handy, but that is the key on Linuxes. You can run `ohai` on a Windows machine and see all the information available:

```
$ ohai
```